# How to access array object value and return it to a new element text content or inner text?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS. I am struggling to write a simple program to access an object's property value from an array and set an interval to cycle between the properties of the objects and place them inside a span after a few seconds.

```
let nameList = [
  {
    title: "Hotel Apple Den",
    location: "Paris"
  },
  {
    title: "Hotel Garden View",
    location: "NY"
  },
  {
    title: "Resident Inn",
    location: "India"
  },
  {
    title: "Indian Villa",
    location: "India"
  }
];
let nameChange = document.querySelector(".randomNameOne");
for (let i = 0; i < nameList.length; i++) {
  document.querySelector(".addText").innerHTML = setInterval(() => {
    `<span> ${nameList[i].title}</span>`;
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to add a delay between each element or an initial delay?

Comment: no. actually, my UI has 4 cards. each of these cards has a title. I want to cycle the titles between each card after every interval. like each card gets all 4 titles, at least once in a cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in following steps:

- Create a variable to store current element of the array.
- Use `setInterval()` and pass a call back to it with the time you want.
- Inside function increase the variable `i`(current element of array).
- Use `insertAdjacentHTML()` instead of `innerHTML`

```js
let nameList = [
  {
    title: "Hotel Apple Den",
    location: "Paris"
  },
  {
    title: "Hotel Garden View",
    location: "NY"
  },
  {
    title: "Resident Inn",
    location: "India"
  },
  {
    title: "Indian Villa",
    location: "India"
  }
];

const shuffle  = (arr) => arr.slice().sort((a,b) => Math.random() - 0.5)

let shuffled = shuffle(nameList)


let i = 0;
const elm = document.querySelector(".addText") 
let interval = setInterval(() => {
 elm.insertAdjacentHTML
("afterend",`<span> ${shuffled[i].title}</span><br>`)
 i++;
 if(i===nameList.length) clearInterval(interval)
},1000)
```

```html
<div class="addText"></div>
```

Comment: I want to add the name to 4 different card-title at random at once. Like card1 get title set as Hotel Apple Den, similarly, card 2 gets Hotel Garden View, and this cycle goes on? is that possible?

Comment: @KunalDas Yes you can you need to create another shuffled array and do the same. I updated the answer tell me if any problem

Comment: can you expain what actually is going on with this shuffle's sort? And btw changed your ans's code where insertAdjacentHTML is written to innerHTML, since i needed it inside the card-title div

Comment: @KunalDas Actually its just a way to shuffle array using `sort()`. `sort()` method should return a number. On the basis of that number it shuffles the array. Here i am creating a random number in range `-0.5` to `0.5` so it shuffles the array.

Comment: also, after reaching the last title, it stops. and even though i am using same class in all cards, only one car is showing the result

Comment: @KunalDas You can use `innerHTML` in this case but node changing `innerHTML` is not nice because when you change it you will lose all references to the children of that particular element.

Comment: Also, note that the change happens only on one card, not to all those having the same class addText